# Any ideas on how to solve this matrix / 2x2D array computation?

Tags: c

I have 2 3x3 matrices each represented in 2D arrays.
First matrix holds elements [ I store PID so,the range of elements could be from millions Iam just simplifying it as A in my actual application it is an integer range A could be 200 and B could be 200000]
e.g., matrix element

```
{ A B C
  B D C
  C F B }
```

second holds weight of each location
e.g., Matrix weight

```
{ 9 7 5
  8 6 1
  7 5 4 }
```

so in the above example B is the heaviest element because its weight is 7+8+4 followed by C etc.,

How do I find out the top 3 highest element ?

One solution is:
Is to store the elements in a separate array A[9][2]( element, value and unique) looping the element matrix and then another loop to go through the value array and filling up the value corresponding to the element.
[ iterate to create a 9x2 key value matrix,iterate to sort, iterate to remove duplicates(since weights need to be consolidated ),  - Is there a better way ? ]

Any other efficient way ? [hint : I need only 3 so i shouldnt use 9x2 ]

Comment: Create an array of unique elements, count (sum) their weights in another array, sort first array by values of second array, ta daa!

Comment: I'd write some code for that, shockingly similar to the algorithm Aziz just tossed out there.

Comment: @AZIZ gave points to your solution but I think there is more efficient way.

Comment: @purpletech do you mean keeping track of the three highest at each step as you add the weights?  That be okay if negative weights were not allowed.

Comment: Wait what, the arrays are really 3x3 and this isn't just a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you know you have only letters `A-Z` available and they are capitals.

```
char elems[3][3] = {
    { 'A', 'B', 'C' },
    { 'B', 'D', 'C' },
    { 'C', 'F', 'B' }
};
```

And you have similarly set up your weights...

You can keep track of counts like this:

```
int counts[26] = {0};

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        counts[elems[i][j] - 'A'] += weights[i][j];
    }
}
```

Then it's just a case of finding the index of the three largest counts, which I'm sure you can do easily.

Comment: Note, if you need to handle negative weights, you'll have to explicitly initialise all your counts to `INT_MIN`.

Comment: good solution. gave points but I updated the question with better assumption. sorry. I really cannot use int counts[26] mine is really a big range its not character A, I did A for simplicity in my example. let me think about it.

Comment: Well you could index it with a hash table.  You have integers, right?  Are you anal about storage?  You can have a reasonably sparse hash table with (for argument's sake) 31 elements.  It would only store a maximum of 9 elements, and chances of every single one colliding are pretty low.  If you're concerned, make the table larger.  Use a prime number.

Answer (score 2):

Forget that they're 2D arrays, and merge the two data sources into a single array (of pairs). For your example, you would get `{{'A', 9}, {'B', 7}, {'C', 5}, {'B', 8}, ...}`. Sort these (for example, with `qsort`), and then scan through the list, summing as you go -- and maintaining the top 3 scored keys you find.

[This solution always works, but only makes sense if the arrays are large, which on re-reading the question they're not].

Comment: Thx. I already gave this solution as one of my answer. this solution uses additional storage (a 9x2 array ) and finding duplicates takes another iteration/computation and also another iteration/computation for sorting. (+1ing )